# "No MimeMessage content" exception when sending SimpleMailMessage

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a very simple email with org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl. Below is the code :

```
SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
mailMessage.setTo(request.getCustomerEmail());
mailMessage.setSubject("someSubject");
mailMessage.setFrom("vincent@myDomain.com");
mailSender.send(mailMessage);
```

This is the exception I get :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: No MimeMessage content
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:459)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:307)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
```

I really don't understand why this happens..

Any idea ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After a couple of hours of struggling, I've found that this is all because the mail I'm creating has no text !

If I add this line, then it works like a charm :

```
mailMessage.setText("blabla");
```

I really got confused by the "No MimeMessage content" message.. Does anybody agree that the message could be more informative, or is it only me ? Does this mean we can't send an email with just a subject and no content ?

Comment: The content can be an empty string, but it has to be something.  Not setting some content is more likely a programming error than an intent to send a message with empty content.

Comment: You saved my time.Faced same issue. I agree that the message could be more informative as the error message is really confusing.