# JavaMailSender with Exception writing Multipart

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

When I used JavaMailSender to send e-mail with attachment, It always failed and throw the exception below:

```java
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Exception writing Multipart
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Exception writing Multipart
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:462)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:359)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:354)
```

Here is my code

```java
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
try {
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setFrom(userName);
    helper.setTo(toAddress);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
    helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("oops..., ", e);
}
mailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: Check file is exit's in FileSystemResource using exists method

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 18):

em, I've solved this problem by luck.

Just set an empty text content with your attachment, like this and it works.

```java
helper.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeText("")), new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
helper.setText("", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

set content type, I resoled this by setting content type as 3rd parameter

helper.addAttachment("Attachment File name", new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)), **"application/pdf"**);

Answer (score 1):

It gives this error if you don't set the text. You need to set text even if you set it to an empty string.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015901/9905202